# How to use vim style ctrl p list in eclipse vrapper?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, vim

I have created `ctags` for my c/c++ code. It helps me in word completion in context of my code tags and also shows me a list of options.

I am able to use same feature in eclipse vrapper (with ctags) but it doesn't show me the list.

Comment: I wish I could have put the image to describe the question better but I do not have enough points :(

Comment: Put it online somewhere and add the link to your question.

Comment: Do you want the ctrl+p feature from vim in eclipse or do you want the ctrl+p feature from eclipse in vim?

Comment: I want the ctrl+p feature from vim in eclipse.

Comment: Vrapper doesn't do contextual menus. If you want that feature, ask for it on Vrapper's [issue tracker](https://github.com/vrapper/vrapper/issues?direction=desc&sort=created&state=closed).

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with the eclipse plugin "easy explore", perhaps this will meet your demand

Comment: Didn't find something like `easy explore` in eclipse market place. Is the repo needs to be included manually?

Comment: This plugin works on win32 platform only. While I am using linux.